# TypeScript interfaces and implementation

Tags: typescript

I was having a play around with TypeScript and interfaces. I have the following piece of code

```
interface Control {
    name: string;
    onSelect():string;
}

class Button {
    name:string="button";
    onSelect = function() {
        return "hello";
    }
}

var a:Button = new Button();
var b:Control = {"name": "arbitrary", "onSelect": () => { return "ahoy!"; }};

var trigger = function(c:Button) {
    console.log(c.name, "says", c.onSelect());
}

trigger(a);
trigger(b);
```

Which compiles and runs without complaining. Can anyone please explain why my `trigger` function accepts `b` even though it expects to get a type `Button` and `b` is of type `Control`.

Even if `Button` were to explicitly implement `Control`, I'm asking for a `Button` not a `Control`. For all intended purposes, `Button` may contain additional members.

Is TypeScript inferring the implementation just because they are structurally the same? Are you allowed to pass an interface where an implementing class is expected? (shouldn't it be the other way around?)

Comment: If `Button` has a private member, only it (or classes that extend from it) will be considered compatible types. You might consider adding a 'dummy' private member if this is the desired behavior.

Comment: I see. I was thinking of adding a dummy member. In your opinion, is strict type enforcing something unnecessary? Does it go against the principles of TS?

Comment: I'd say it's rarely productive, but there are always exceptions. It's somewhat of a design smell if `trigger` actually depends on aspects of `Button` other than the members it uses, after all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in [this TypeScript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system):

> One of TypeScript’s core principles is that type checking focuses on the shape that values have. This is sometimes called “duck typing” or “structural typing”.

In ["duck typing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing):

> If it looks like a duck and swims like a duck, then in it's likely a duck.

In other words, TypeScript examines the shape (methods and properties) of a supplied object or type. If the supplied object contains all the properties and methods described by an interface, then the object can, in all likelihood, be treated as an object that is compatible with the described interface.

In your example, your interface and class look exactly the same, so TypeScript treats your object as compatible with the described interface.

If you [examine the generated JavaScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20Control%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20onSelect()%3Astring%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Button%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3Astring%3D%22button%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20onSelect%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22hello%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20a%3AButton%20%3D%20new%20Button()%3B%0Avar%20b%3AControl%20%3D%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22arbitrary%22%2C%20%22onSelect%22%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20return%20%22ahoy!%22%3B%20%7D%7D%3B%0A%0Avar%20trigger%20%3D%20function(c%3AButton)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(c.name%2C%20%22says%22%2C%20c.onSelect())%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atrigger(a)%3B%0Atrigger(b)%3B), note that there is no mention of your interface at all - this is because TypeScript Interfaces are essentially developer-supplied type metadata that help TypeScript validate type compatibility.

Comment: Is there any way to enfore strict type checking? This makes it easier for me to overlook subtle nuances that might introduce problems down the line.

Comment: @Andrei - Type safety is not "The JavaScript Way™" Many JS programmers like the fact that they can fly fast and loose with types. TS adds some type-safety, but it's still looser than C/C++/C#/Java/etc.

Comment: @Andrie: Further, as John mentions, if you make your object or interfaces look different, then TS will warn you.

Answer (score 2):

Both your `interface` and `class` have the same implementation, so while its expecting a `Button` you are passing in a compatible object (has name that returns string and onSelect function that returns a string)

If you add another property to `Button` such as `greeting: string` it will error on `trigger(b)` saying that its not valid.

```
interface Control {
    name: string;
    onSelect:() => string; // this is another way to write function that returns a string
}

class Button implements Control {
    name:string="button";
    onSelect = function() {
        return "hello";
    }
    greeting: string; // adding this will cause trigger(b) to fail
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to enable strict type checking? Would it be something you consider unnecessary?

Comment: @AndreiNemes I don't think its necessary. Once your class has any other kind of property or isn't exactly match the interface it wouldn't allow it.